# Nextjs 14 (or 13) slow initial load via Link to page with params to collect (firestore) data - loading not showing

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm using Nextjs 14, but I had the issue as well in Nextjs 13. I am loading a list of places, and from there, I link to an individual place details page. But the initial switch from the overview page to the details page could take a second but doesn't show the Loading page as it should.

Normally the Loading page is directly activated after a click on a link using Link from Nextjs. I follow the [Nextjs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating), but the problem starts when I collect the data in the single details page, using the params in my fetch request.

I have set up a loading page as per the docs.

Once I have loaded 1 individual page, and navigate further to another one, it's direct. *It's only on the first load, and only via the overview page*.

I'm using Firestore for my data and the Nextjs fetch to collect it. To do this I'm using the params as part of the fetch request.

**This is my individual details page:**

```
import fetchCoffeePlace from "@/api/fetchCoffeeplace"
import NotFoundCoffeePlace from "./components/NotFoundCoffeePlace"
import SingleCoffeePage from "./components/SingleCoffeePage"

async function getCoffeePlace(id: string) {
    const coffee = await fetchCoffeePlace(id)

    if (!coffee) { return <NotFoundCoffeePlace /> }

    return coffee
}

export default async function Page({ params }: { params: { 'coffee': string } }) {
    const id = params['coffee']
    const data = await getCoffeePlace(id)
    const coffeeplace = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))

    return (
        <SingleCoffeePage coffee={coffeeplace} />
    )
}
```

Is this the correct way to use Params to fetch data and activate the Loading page in Nextjs 13/14?